# Saving Many to Many relationship to database in Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony, many-to-many, save

In my Symfony2 project I have two related entities: Users and Favorites. They have a many-to-many relationship.

My application works as follows:
In my Twig-page I have an few items with a button 'Add to Favorites'. When you click the button my controller saves the item_id in the Favorites column. But then I want to save
the user who added the item to his favorites and here my application fails.

The User and the favorite exist but the joincolumn between Users and Favorites remains empty. 
I also don't receive any kind of errors.

Here is my code:

Entity Users

```
class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Favorites", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_favorite",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="favorite_id", referencedColumnName="favorite_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $favorite;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->favorite = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addFavorite(\Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Favorites $favorite)
    {
        $this->favorite[] = $favorite;

        return $this;
    }
...
```

Entity Favorites

```
class Favorites
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="favorite", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addUser(\Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users $user)
    {
        $this->user[] = $user;    
        return $this;
    }
```

My controller

```
public function showNewsAction()
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');    
        $itemId=$request->request->get('itemId');
        if($itemId != NULL)
        {
        //MAKE NEW FAVORITE AND ADD TO DATABASE LINKED WITH ITEM
        $favorite = new Favorites();
        $favorite->setItemId($itemId);

         //LINK FAVORITE ID WITH USER ID IN JOINCOLUMN
        $userId = 6;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $user = $em->getRepository('GeoCityTroopersBundle:Users')->find($userId);

        $favorite->addUser($user);
        $em->persist($favorite); 

        //I TRIED THIS TOO, BUT IT FAILED
        /*$user->addFavorite($favorite);
        $em->persist($user);*/

        $em->flush();
```

Comment: It failed... ? You got an error or it doesn't do the trick ? If you have an error, please post it.

Answer (score 26):

You were close there. For doctrine many-to-many relationships, you need to call both add methods

```
$favorite->addUser($user);
$user->addFavorite($favorite);

$em->persist($favorite); 
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This should do the trick. In [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) they do this, but don't mention it too explicitly. Not sure why either because lots of people run into this (myself included).

Comment: It said in comment "I TRIED THIS TOO, BUT IT FAILED". Maybe there is another error... Actually, you just need to update the owning side of the association so the first line of your answer is not mandatory.

Comment: When I do --> 
$favorite->addUser($user);
$user->addFavorite($favorite);
$em->persist($favorite); 
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

I get this error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function move() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony13\src\Geo\CityTroopersBundle\Entity\Users.php</b> on line <b>653</b>

I looked in my Code, and it refers to a function I don't call at all.

Comment: from what i could make out form the url, i updated your link to the docs

Answer (score 9):

As explained here, only the owning side is responsible for the connection management :
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association

So only

```
$user->addFavorite($favorite);
```

should persist, and not

```
$favorite->addUser($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like indicated by Cedric, adding a record for a many to many relation is done only in one direction and it depends on how you defined the relation: adding can be done only by the parent entity of the relation, so in your case you must use:

```
$user->addFavorite($favorite);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your line :

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="favorite_id", referencedColumnName="favorite_id")
```

The

```
name="favorite_id"
```

part refers to the columns in the join table, whereas the

```
referencedColumnName="favorite_id"
```

refers to the id in the favorite table which usualy is simply "id". You should try :

```
    /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Favorites", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_favorite",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="favorite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $favorite;
```