# Symfony - persisting ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any other way I could write this bit of code better? Am I missing something here?

```
$user->addEntity($entity);
$entity->addUser($user);


$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($entity);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Many to Many relationship to database in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159307/saving-many-to-many-relationship-to-database-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add only from the [owning side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side) of the relation; then you can `persist` only that object and flush it.

For example, if your annotations are like this

```
class User
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", inversedBy="users")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_entity")
   */
  protected $entities
}

class Entity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="entities")
   */
  protected $users;
}
```

you can do this

```
$user->add($entity); 

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->flush();
```

You can skip `persist` if `$user` is fetched from db and if it's not a new object.